# How do I properly tokenize a moderately complex shell script into tokens suitable for docker-compose.yml

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I want to turn this shell script:

```
 (prog1 &) && \
 (prog2 -d -l &) && \
 sleep 0.5 && \
 prog3
```

into a list for docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  math:
    command: [ "(prog1 &)", "\\&\\&", "(prog2 -d -l &)", "\\&\\&", "sleep", "0.5", "\\&\\&", "prog3" ]
```

My entrypoint is `bash`.

Where I am uncertain is:

- how do I handle the subshells? Right now it looks like bash is trying to find an executable "(prog1 &)" instead of properly parsing that part.
- what do I need to escape? I think I remember I needed to escape && so that it is passed as argument to my entrypoint `bash`, but apart from that I don't really get what I need to escape.

Comment: you should add this to script file `.sh` and run the script from the command

Comment: http://oneclickpaste.com/124807/

Comment: The only way `(prog1 &)` can fail is if `prog1` fails to start up at all; `&&` is simply testing the startup process, not the exit status of `prog1`. You may want to consider running all three programs in separate containers.

Comment: If you want to pass a whole script to a shell entry point, you actually need to pass it as a single string. If your entry point really is just bash, then you need to prepend `-c` to indicate to the shell that you are passing an inline script, i.e. `[ "-c", "<The Script>" ]`. To be on the save side, you should be passing your desired shell explicitly, i.e. `[ "/bin/bash", "-c", "<The Script>" ]`. Make sure to properly escape everything, or simply follow best practices and put everything into a manageble script, that can be invoked easily.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should run this as three separate containers.  In Docker Compose you can specify a separate `command:` for each container, even if they’re built off the same image.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  math_prog1:
    build: .
    command: prog1
  math_prog2:
    build: .
    command: prog2
```

If you really must run all three things in one container, your best bet is to use your shell script as-is.  `COPY` it into your image (or, if you must, use `volumes:` to inject it) and make the script be the main container process.  Remember that if `prog1` or `prog2` fail for any reason then you’ll have no visibility into this, and your only recourse will be to also restart the otherwise healthy components (and if `prog3` fails it will take the other two programs with it).

Comment: the services depend on each other, in a way that would take time for me to understand. Presumably there is network communication going on, but I don't really know what channels they use to communicate. For all I know, there could be a shared file. Is there a way to properly express that they should be able to communicate via network, no matter the port?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do anything, though you do need to configure the services with each others’ service names as host names.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) is essential reading here.